# How to control line size when working with autoplot() in the forecast package

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting

I am used to controlling line size in `geom_line(size=1)` in `ggplot`. I can't seem to find a way to control line size in the `autoplot()` function in the `forecast` package, For example, given the following code, how can I make the line size thicker?

```
> library(forecast)
> d.arima <- forecast::auto.arima(AirPassengers)
> autoplot(forecast::forecast(d.arima, h = 10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ggfortify`

```
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(forecast::forecast(d.arima, h = 10), predict.size = 3, size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: @Ben try: `ggfortify:::autoplot.forecast(forecast::forecast(d.arima, h = 10), predict.size = 3, size = 2)`